# Unital channel which is not mixed unitary

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, nielsen-and-chuang, kraus-representation

How to prove that for a multi-qubit system a unital channel is not necessarily mixed unitary? This is Problem 8.3 in Nielsen and Chuang. Here's a snippet of the text:

[image]

Shall I need to take two parallel channels to prove this thing, and instead of $\rho_{AB}$ even I will take $I_{AB}$? It's the case of separable. Can someone please help me prove this for a multi-qubit system?

Comment: Can you write out your problem precisely? With my understanding, a mixed unitary channel would be unital.

Comment: the problem is asking the opposite of what you wrote: prove that unital doesn't imply mixed-unitary. This is also discussed in chapter 4 of [Watrous' book](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~watrous/TQI/TQI) where they give an explicit example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Determining whether there exists an equivalent set of unitary Kraus operators](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/determining-whether-there-exists-an-equivalent-set-of-unitary-kraus-operators)

Comment: @AdamZalcman it took me a while to find the connection between that question and this one, but eventually I did find: **"Also as Adam has answered, qubit channels are mixed unitary if and only if they are unital. This is no longer true in dimension 3 and higher."** However this question asked "Can someone please help me how to prove it is not unital for a ***multi-qubit system***." The "if and only if" theorem for single-qubit channels would no longer apply right?

Comment: Indeed. The answer there has a counterexample, but no proof. I agree and have retracted my VTC.

Answer (score 1):

### Unital channel which is not mixed unitary

Consider the following two-qubit quantum channel
$$
\Xi(X)=A_0XA_0^\dagger+A_1XA_1^\dagger\tag1
$$
where
$$
A_0=\begin{bmatrix}
1&&&\\
&&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\\
&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&&\\
&&&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\end{bmatrix}\quad
A_1=\begin{bmatrix}
0&&&\\
&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&&\\
&&-\frac{1}{\sqrt2}&\\
&&&\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\\
\end{bmatrix}.\tag2
$$
We have $\Xi(I)=I$, so $\Xi$ is unital. Moreover, $A_0$ and $A_1$ are linearly independent and $A_0^2$, $A_0A_1$, $A_1A_0$ and $A_1^2$ are also linearly independent. Therefore, by theorem $2.31$ on page $97$ in John Watrous' book *The Theory of Quantum Information* (see below), the channel $\Xi$ is an extreme point of the convex set of quantum channels. In other words, $\Xi$ is not a non-trivial convex combination of other quantum channels. In particular, $\Xi$ is not a non-trivial convex combination of unitary channels. Finally, $\Xi$ is not unitary since it sends $|01\rangle$ to a mixed state.

### Conditions for a channel to be an extreme point

For ease of reference I reproduce the theorem used above:

> Theorem $2.31$ (Choi) Let $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ be complex Euclidean spaces, let$^1$ $\Phi\in C(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})$ be a channel, and let $\{A_a:a\in\Sigma\}\subset L(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ be a linearly independent set of operators satisfying$^2$
> $$
> \Phi(X)=\sum_{a\in\Sigma}A_aXA_a^\dagger\tag{2.174}
> $$
> for all $X\in L(\mathcal{X})$. The channel $\Phi$ is an extreme point of the set $C(\mathcal{X}, \mathcal{Y})$ if and only if the collection
> $$
> \{A_b^\dagger A_a:(a,b)\in\Sigma\times\Sigma\}\subset L(\mathcal{X})\tag{2.175}
> $$
> of operators is linearly independent.

---

<sup>$^1$ The symbol $C(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{Y})$ denotes the set of all quantum channels, i.e. completely positive and trace-preserving linear maps $\Phi:L(\mathcal{X})\to L(\mathcal{Y})$, see definition $2.13$ on page $73$.

$^2$ In the book, the adjoint is denoted $A^*$, see page $11$. Here, I am using the more common notation $A^\dagger$.</sup>